# how can i stop event bubbling without stopPropagation method

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-bubbling, stoppropagation

there is some html code like this:

```
<ul>
    <li id='root' class='tree-node'>
      root
      <ul>
        <li class='tree-node' id='node1'>node1</li>
        <li class='tree-node' id='node2'>node2</li>
        <li class='tree-node' id='node3'>node3</li>
        <li class='tree-node' id='node4'>node4
            <ul>
                <li class='tree-node' id='node4-1' >node4-1</li>
                <li class='tree-node' id='node4-2' >node4-2</li>                    
            </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>

<ul>
```

i want to bind click event to each tag which has tree-node class

and also binding click event to document

here is my code:

```
$(".tree-node").click(function(e){
    console.log($(this).attr("id"));
});

$(document).click(function(e){
    console.log("document clicked!");   
});
```

Is there any alternative for stopPropagation() to stop event bubbling from node4-2 to its parents?

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/R6ySc/

Comment: Why you do not want to use stopPropagation?

Comment: because i want to invoke document click event

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could just use the document click event and handle everything from there.

```
$(document).click(function(e){
    console.log("document clicked!");    
    var t = $(e.target);
    if(t.attr("class") == "tree-node") {
        console.log("tree node clicked");
    }
});​
```

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/R6ySc/3/

as an alternative, you can also specify a selector in the onclick event for the document (check the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for this):

```
$(document).on("click", ".tree-node", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log("tree node '" + $(this).attr("id") + "' clicked");
});​
```

for reference, check the comments below

Comment: More conventionally (since jQuery 1.7), you might use `$.(document).on('click', '.tree-node', function(){...})`, in which case the clicked node appears as `this` inside the function.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot: good point. However I tried this in a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/R6ySc/4/) and then there's the propagation issue again. Also, the regular document click (outside the tree) is no longer handled...

Comment: Reinder, straightforwardly yes. The event will indeed fire all the way up the DOM tree as it bubbles. My point was incomplete. I should have added that you can (when necessary) reject non-target clicks in the handler by testing `(this == e.target)`. See [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R6ySc/5/). And the regular document click (outside the tree) is quite correctly not handled.

Comment: Even better, `e.stopPropagation()` will prevent the event firing on elements other than the target. This is maybe counter-intuitive as the event must have bubbled for `document` to be handling the click in the first place! See http://jsfiddle.net/R6ySc/6/.

Comment: the OP explicit ask to not use `e.stopPropagation()` , so how to get the id clicked on in the first example (it still bubbles up)?

Comment: i voted down to fast and cannot undo, hower , behind the scene there is still bubblingup, but 0 side effect :)